# Conditional format cell based off other cells

Tags: google-sheets

I want one cell that's blank to change colors based off another cell containing text. But once the blank cell has a text put in I want the color to go away. I have not tried anything because I'm unsure how to code this.

So if 
A1(contains text),B1(blank cell) turns red. Once B1(contains text), B1 turns white.

I only want B1 to turn red if A1(contains text).If A1(is blank) I want B1 to stay white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Apply to Range `B:B`

Custom Formula is `=and(A:A<>"",B:B="")`

if column A has a length greater than 0 and column B has a length equal to 0 make column B red.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Worked perfect

Comment: My votes don't show yet tho. I only have a score of 13/15.